# Change position of Fragment in DrawerLayout dynamically when openDrawer and closeDrawer

Tags: position, fragment, drawerlayout

I used a lot of time to solve my problem, but I can't find a way to do it.
My problem is something like the picture in link: http://goo.gl/dffOhJ
(Sorry, I do not have reputation enough to post image)

My main_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:background="#F78B1E"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My question is how can I dynamically change position of Fragment when Drawer open or close?
Can anyone help me.
Thank in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Implement [DrawerListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.DrawerListener.html) and in its callback: `onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset)` change position of `content_frame` (translate horizontally).